# Why I can't connect to the url?

Tags: php, android, url

```
String log_url = "http://192.168.1.11/Rep/logini.php";

URL url = new URL(log_url);

HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(nam, "UTF-8") + "&" + 
    URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(loc, "UTF-8");
bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
outputStream.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

While executing this code I couldn't connect to the `url.Disconnecting` in this line `OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();`.

The message in the console like:

> handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400024DF,
>   flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9 01-27 16:59:55.848
>   12282-12289/com.example.focture.medicalrep D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest
>   : len=0x34

Comment: Have you enabled Internet permssion in Manifest?

Comment: does both your phone and server connected to same network?

Comment: Yes I have enabled the Internet Permission

Comment: @KarthikCP Yes my phone and the server in ame network

Comment: both the phone and computer are connected to your wifi?

Comment: @jibin Why are you using connection.setDoInput(true); ? Try removing that line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to connect to yoursel...

if this is your ip **192.168.1.11** then use **localhost** instead

```
String log_url = "http://localhost/Rep/logini.php";
```

Comment: I trying to connect to the url from my phone to the server.So i gave the IP

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(nam, "UTF-8") + "&" + 
    URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(loc, "UTF-8");
    URL obj = new URL("http://192.168.1.11/Rep/logini.php");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(post_data.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
    }
```

Comment: Error in thei line "  os.write(post_data);"  Again Showing the app is running and in console message"D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
D/jdwp: processIncoming
D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40003336, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
D/jdwp: processIncoming
D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40003337, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
D/jdwp: processIncoming"

Comment: @jibin : Updated.. try again

Comment: Tried,but in this line "    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();", it shows app is running and the same message in console a lot